# "sandboxed" view engine for MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewengine

I'm curious if anyone knows of an MVC view engine that is more "sandboxed".

Specifically, I'm looking to create a multi-tennant user-customizable website.. not quite Myspace, but with similar theming capabilities.

The problem, of course, with MVC and ASP.NET is that you can't just give end users access to raw ASP.NET code.  So, i'm thinking of something that allows specific tags that the user can insert but without the ability to execute code (not even JavaScript).

My first thought was using XSLT, but I don't want end users to have to know XSLT, and i'd really just prefer something that was html-like.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown). There are a [couple](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/) of [implementations](http://aspnetresources.com/blog/markdown_announced) for .NET. This very same site uses this markup language for formatting questions and answers and I find it great.